# How to hide a text using javascript?

Tags: javascript

**html code**

```
<button id="signin" name="signin" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
                    Sign in</button>
                   <label id="myDiv">Hello</label>
```

**javascript code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){       

    document.getElementById('signin').onclick = function () {

        document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display="none";
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: What does not work in the code you already have?  Do you have a script error?  Are you including jQuery script in your page?

Comment: This is already working with hiding hello text on click of button..Whats the issue then ?

Comment: As other said the code above is working. Are there any errors in console? Also check if the id `myDiv` exist on your page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#signin").click(function() {
    $("#myDiv").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button id="signin" name="signin" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
    Sign in</button>
  <label id="myDiv">Hello</label>
</body>
```

If you are using jQuery already, why don't you try

```
$("#myDiv").hide();
```

**Update:**

Based on your comment, You could write the following event handler

```
$("#signin").click(function() {
    $("#myDiv").hide();
});
```

**More Edit**: Added a code snippet.

Comment: It cant help. I want to hide this text after clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery try:

```
$("#signin").click(function() {
    $("#myDiv").css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

If you're using pure js try:

```
document.getElementById("signin").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use Below JavaScript:

```
signin.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "none";
}, false);
```

Here is [Working DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/9qurfk9m/)

Answer (score 0):

**Without** jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("signin").onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById("myDiv").setAttribute('style','display:none');
};
```

more about [Element.setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Comment: @RoshanPatil Sweet, set it to _answered_ if it's sorted ;)